# Query with predicted output using Multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, pandas

I'm hoping to better understand the predicted output of the dependent variable using a multiple linear regression. Specifically, I'm getting negative predicted outputs when altering specific independent variables.

I'll display an example `df` below and explain the independent variables

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant

d = ({
    'Date' :    ['01/01/18','01/01/18','01/01/18','01/01/18','02/01/18','02/01/18','02/01/18','02/01/18'],
    'Country' :    ['US','US','US','MX','US','US','MX','MX'],   
    'Occurrences' :    [1,5,3,4,2,5,10,2],   
    'Turnover' :    [100000,40000,500000,8000,10000,300000,80000,1000],     
    'Medium' :    ['S1','S2','S1','S2','S1','S1','S1','S2'],     
    'Day' :    ['Saturday','Saturday','Saturday','Saturday','Sunday','Sunday','Sunday','Sunday'],              
})

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# One hot Encoding           
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df[['Country','Medium','Day']], drop_first=True)
df = df.join(one_hot)

df = df[['Country_US','Medium_S2','Day_Sunday','Occurrences','Turnover']]
```

Model:

```
# Extract features and labels
features = df.iloc[:,0:-1].values
labels = df.iloc[:,-1].values

# Cross validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)

# Create Linear Model
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# CoEfficient and Intercept
#print(regressor.coef_)
#print(regressor.intercept_)

# Predict the Output
y_Pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print(regressor.predict([0, 1, 0, 1]))

# Determine multicollinearity
X = add_constant(df)

VIF = pd.Series([variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) 
               for i in range(X.shape[1])], 
              index=X.columns)

print(VIF)

const          19.914550
Country_US      2.029087
Medium_S2       2.165254
Day_Sunday      1.495758
Occurrences     1.364778
Turnover        1.706089
```

So the variables I've plugged in are: 

`Country_Group : 0
Medium_S2 : 1
Day_Sunday = 0
Occurrences :  1`

I understand `Linear regression` does not respect the bounds of 0. But is there a method I can ensure the output is a positive number without affecting the validity of the model?

The minimum output that can be generated is zero. It cannot be a negative number.

Output:

```
[-95500.]
```

Comment: What is your research question? Are Occurrences categorical or continuous? Is there a reason why Time Started would need to be continuous?

Comment: You need to base it on prior literature. I do not know what the Occurrences variable is, bit TimeStarted could be grouped by morning, afternoon, and night. You might try both dummy coding and making it a continuous variable and see what the outcome is. Just make sure to include this in your report.

Comment: Why not regress log(y) on the features, and, then take the exponent of the predicted value? From the sample you've shared, the turnover looks right-skewed so the log transform will have the additional benefit of making it "normal".

Comment: Thanks @user2522806. Could you maybe provide an example in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you could try fit a model on the log of the labels and take the exponent of the predicted value

```
labels = np.log(labels)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)

# Create Linear Model
regressor = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# CoEfficient and Intercept
print(regressor.coef_)
print(regressor.intercept_)

# Predict the Output
y_Pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print(np.exp(regressor.predict([[1, 0, 1, 0, 3]])))
```

The output is

```
[-4.77563348  0.52967564 -4.77563348  1.81217047 -1.02009026]
19.04716416404977
[623.67313587]
```

Comment: Thanks @user2522806